# Imputing NaN values of a column with values in another column based on counts

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 datasets as follows.

Dataset 1

```
| impute    | city1         |
|--------   |------------   |
| 1875.0    | Medan         |
| 274.0     | Yogyakarta    |
| 257.0     | Jakarta       |
| 71.0      | Bekasi        |
| 68.0      | Bandung       |
| 41.0      | London        |
| 41.0      | Purwokerto    |
| 36.0      | Malang        |
| 33.0      | Manchester    |
| 29.0      | Denpasar      |
| 27.0      | Surabaya      |
| 26.0      | Bogor         |
| 24.0      | Semarang      |
| 22.0      | Surakarta     |
```

**Dimensions = 248 x 2**

Dataset 2

```
| city          |
|------------   |
| NaN           |
| Yogyakarta    |
| Medan         |
| NaN           |
| Medan         |
| Medan         |
| NaN           |
| Tangerang     |
| NaN           |
| NaN           |
| Tangerang     |
| NaN           |
| Medan         |
| NaN           |
| NaN           |
| NaN           |
| NaN           |
| NaN           |
| Medan         |
```

**Dimensions  13866 x 1**

I want to impute Nan values in city (dataset 2) with values in city1 (dataset 1) .

Dataset 2 has 3563 Nan values . So , I want to impute 1874 of them with Medan , 273 with Yogyakarta , 256 with Jakarta and so on randomly (any 1874 NaN's out of 3563 NaN's ) . The impute column in dataset 1 sums up to 3563 (equal to number of NaN values in Dataset 2).

So In short number of NaN values to be replaced by a city in Dataset 1 should be equal to the value in impute column.

Can somebody please help me with this.

Comment: So the number of nan is equal to the sum of inpute values?

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```py
df1['city'].repeat(df1['impute']).sample(frac=1)
```

to repeat the values in the `city` column as many times as the number in the `impute` column, and shuffle the result. Then use

```py
df2['city'].isna()
```

to find NaN cities, and use that to assign the imputed values.

Put it together you end up with

```py
df2['city'].loc[df2['city'].isna()] = df1['city'].repeat(df1['no']).sample(frac=1).values
```